# How can I view my comment history?

Tags: support, comments, user-profiles

When providing a comment on a question or answer, I usually like to check back to see if there's anything else I can follow-up with (be it someone else's answer/comment or an edit to the main question).

Is there a way to view comments I have made from my user profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your profile, select the *activity* tab, then the *comments* filter: [Click me!](https://superuser.com/users/182949/kruug?tab=activity&sort=comments)

Comment: Woah!  Look at that...thanks for pointing that out!